# Attributes of the helper validates_length_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

Is there any attribute in the helper `validates_length_of` that makes the field tested accept only one of 2 fixed sizes, such as 10 and 12?
In case, if the user sent the value 11 will not be accepted.

I already researched some attributes, but found nothing

The code I tried to run was this:

```
validates_length_of :field, is: 14 || 18
```

The code snippet does not produce an error, but only takes the first value

Comment: I don't think so. You could make a custom validator that's called in a callback that will ensure that the length is only what you want it to be. As it looks, `is: ` only takes one number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `||` is ruby boolean `or` operator, it returns first argument if it is non-falsey and the second otherwise.

Length validator does not accept array for `is` in current rails, so for your case you'll have to write a custom validator:

```
validate :length_of_my_field

private def length_of_my_field
  errors.add(:field, "should have length of 12 or 18") unless [12, 18].include?(field.size)
end
```